# Is it possible to make the node command see a node_modules folder on a different location than the specified one?

Tags: node.js

I know I can install Node.js libraries with the command `npm` from the command line... So, if I type:

```
npm install mylibrary
```

It'll create a `node_modules` folder on my current location and it'll install `mylibrary` (if it exists on npm)... Let's say that I create a Node.js code using it as the following:

```js
const mylibrary = require('mylibrary')
mylibrary.doSomething()
```

Since I've installed this library on my current folder with the last command, this node.js script will work only if I save it on a file on my terminal current location as well. If I name this file as `file.js`, I can execute it with:

```
node file.js
```

Well, my problem is that I have a very specific case where the node_modules folder cannot exist in the same location that my `file.js`. Also, I'd like to avoid having to install `mylibrary` globally. Is there any way of defining as a parameter the path that the command `node` will search for the `node_modules` folder? I've checked `node --help` and it seems there's a lot of options, but I didn't manage to make it work. Is it possible to do? Can I use a node_modules folder that's neither the one of my `file.js` path or a global installed library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a link for the node_modules folder. For example, to create the [symbolink link in Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link) do this:

```
cd /path/to/script/folder
ln -s /path/to/where/you/can/have/node_modules node_modules
```

If you can't have the link, use the full path to the node_modules folder in the require, for example:

```
const mylibrary = require('/path/to/node_modules/mylibrary')
```

Also, you can solve the problem by using the `NODE_PATH` environment variable, set it like this

```
export NODE_PATH=/path/to/node_modules
```